# HTML Required and disabled button

Tags: jquery, html

I've found several ways on making a button enabled (from disabled-state) by checking if input fields have been filled in. But I have yet to see a solution that just checks if there is data in a field/div that have the HTML5 "required" in it. Isnt there a simple solution (Jquery or native JS) that makes this possible? It would seem so simple like it would be a HTML5 functionality, but I might be missing a point?

Answer (score 1):

That would have been just the same.

Try this:

```
<input type="text" required class="required" /> // add the class
```

jQuery code:

```
if($('.required').val() != '') {
   // do the coding and enable the button...
}
```

Using this, you will check for the element which has the class required rather than the element attribute of required.

However, the code for the required element is as:

```
$('[required]').val() != ''
```

You can use an element selector alongwith this to get the value of that element. Then use this in the `if else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this sometimes to assure all required fields have values:

```
var isValid = true;

$(':input[required]').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).val()) {
        isValid = false;
    }
});
if(isValid)){
    //do submit stuff
}
```